# How to use linux bash commands inside a perl script?Getting errors on using it inside perl script

Tags: linux, perl

I know this question is pretty trivial,but still i am stuck.
I have used system(),exec() and back ticks but solution I am not getting proper.
So what exactly I want is,I want to run a command from my perl script.

Here is an example:-

Suppose Command I want to execute is

```
  /scratch/abc/def/xyz/newfold/newfile.py --action=remove;
```

check.txt:-

```
Installation root: /scratch/abc/def/xyz
```

Install.pl:-

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Cwd;
my $now=cwd;
print "############################";
print "*****DELETING THE CURRENT SERVICE*****\n";
my $dir = $ENV{'PWD'};
#my $dir = /scratch/Desktop;
my $inst=`grep -i 'Installation root' $dir/check.txt  `;
my $split=`echo "$inst" | awk '{print \$(3)}'`;         ## this will give the     "/scratch/abc/def/xyz" path

#chdir ( $split);          //Trying to change the directory so that pwd will become till xyz.
qx(echo "cd $split");

$now=cwd;
print $now;
my $dele = `echo "$split/newfold/newfile.py --action=remove;"`;     //Problem is here it gets out from the $split directory and could not go inside and execute the command.
print $dele;
```

Output Expected is:-
It should go inside the directory and execute the sub directory commands.
Please suggest how can i execute command line things easily without exiting the session.

Comment: `$inst` includes the end-of-line character. `chomp` it before you use it to set `$split`. Then you'll need to `chomp $split`, too.

Answer (score 0):

Every system command executed thru Perl will inherit the current working directory (cwd) of the program. The chdir() will let you change the cwd to a different directory and so, inherit this new dir to the system commands executed.

If you do not want to change the cwd of the script, one simple way is to change the working directory using "cd" in concatenation (";") with the commands that you want to execute. Having this in mind, you can try something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Cwd;

my $cwd = getcwd();

print "CWD: $cwd\n";

print "############################";
print "*****DELETING THE CURRENT SERVICE*****\n";

unless (-e "$cwd/check.txt") {
   print "-E-: File ($cwd/check.txt) not found in dir: $cwd\n";
   exit 0;
}

### Grep the /scratch/Desktop/check.txt, if the user launches
### the script at /scratch/Desktop directory
my $inst=`grep -i 'Installation root' $cwd/check.txt`;

chomp($inst);

### Regexp could be simpler to remove label
$inst =~ s/.*root\:\s*//;

print "Installation Root: $inst\n";

### Here the concatenation is used to chdir before the script execution
### Changed to system() since you want to dump the outputs

system("cd $inst; $inst/newfold/newfile.py --action=remove");

print "Done!\n";
```